# I need to use same ID content in two different DIVs. How do I do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Case is this. I have a website with two different layouts for browser and mobile. The content should be same with both and i've created DIVs with unique IDs. In short the code is this...

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .browser {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
    .browser {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="browser">
  <div id="content">Blaa blaa blaa</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
  <div><!--Need to get content from "content" id here--></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: So basically the `div#content` is a full copy, identical in both versions? Are all your selectors for each version starting with either `.mobile` or `.browser`?

Comment: You can't have data of one `id` into another, as `id` is unique. So rather use `class = content` because `class` names can be same but not `id`.

Comment: That's not how responsive web design is done. You don't serve mirrors of the same content with different formats in the same page and toggle between them using media queries. You use media queries to make adjustments to a single layout.

Comment: BoltClock is correct . . . but you can do set the content like this: `document.querySelector(".mobile Div").textContent = document.querySelector("#content").textContent;`

Comment: Basically think of it the other way round. You have one copy of the content and you change its styling depending on the width of the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use same `id` twice, instead you can use same `class` name for multiple elements..